# How do i pass a list from deserialized JSON to a view into a Select List

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Im setting up an App for my company but im relatively new at programming. Now i am trying to talk to an API -> get values -> pass values into a select list - > make the list redirect to another page. Now i'm  running into an issue passing the values from my controller to a select list in the view. Ive googled how to setup select lists and how to populate it with a list but i cant seem to figure it out. i need a push in the right direction. what am i doing wrong. 
my class:

```
public class ApiCalls
{
    Login login = new Login();

    public List<string> GetLeafSwitchProfiles()
    {
        string token = login.Apilogin();
        var client = new RestClient("https://10.23.175.1/api/node/mo/uni/infra.json?query-target=subtree&target-subtree-class=infraNodeP");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddCookie("APIC-cookie", token);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            LeafSwitchesProfileModel.Rootobject rootobject = (LeafSwitchesProfileModel.Rootobject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeafSwitchesProfileModel.Rootobject>(response.Content);
            List<string> leafprofiles = new List<string>();
            foreach (var num in rootobject.imdata)
            {
               //leafprofiles.Add(num.infraNodeP.attributes.name);
               string name = num.infraNodeP.attributes.name;
                leafprofiles.Add(name);
            }
          return leafprofiles;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //Pick switch
    ApiCalls apiCalls = new ApiCalls();
    ViewBag.test = apiCalls.GetLeafSwitchProfiles(); 

    return View();  
}
```

my View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.test)
    {
        <h2>@item.Name</h2>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `List<string> GetLeafSwitchProfiles` method returns a `List` of `string`. Convert the list to an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` by adding the following in your Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //Pick switch
    ApiCalls apiCalls = new ApiCalls();
    ViewBag.test = new SelectList(apiCalls.GetLeafSwitchProfiles()); 

    return View();  
}
```

Now, populate your SelectList by:

```
<select asp-items="ViewBag.test"></select>
```

Comment: So simple yet exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.